# What combination of columns should index have to speed up the query?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

```
UPDATE feedback_aggregated_fact a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent) overallmax_scored
            , MIN(feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent) overallmin_scored
            , AVG(feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent) overallavg_scored
            , ROUND(stddev(feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent)) overallst_dev
            , ROUND(variance(feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent)) overallvarian
            , MAX(tot_que_cat_score) cat_max_scored
            , MIN(tot_que_cat_score) cat_min_scored
            , AVG(tot_que_cat_score) cat_avg_scored
            , ROUND(stddev(tot_que_cat_score)) cat_st_dev
            , ROUND(variance(tot_que_cat_score)) cat_varian
            , MAX(tot_que_score) max_scored
            , MIN(tot_que_score) min_scored
            , AVG(tot_que_score) avg_scored
            , STDDEV(tot_que_score) st_dev
            , VARIANCE(tot_que_score) varian
            , feedbackname
            , fdf.feedback_id
            , faculty_id
            , frf.que_category
            , frf.queid  
         FROM feedback_details_fact fdf 
         JOIN feedback_response_fact frf 
           ON frf.feedback_fact_id = fdf.entity_id 
          AND fdf.latest_flag='Y' 
          AND frf.answer_rowstate != -1 
        WHERE fdf.feedback_entity_type_id IN (1,7,8) 
          AND tot_que_score IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP 
           BY feedback_id
            , faculty_id
            , que_category
            , queid
            ) b 
    ON b.faculty_id = a.faculty_id 
   AND b.feedback_id = a.feedback_id 
   AND a.question_category = b.que_category 
   AND a.question_id = b.queid
   SET a.feedback_max_scored = b.overallmax_scored
     , a.feedback_min_scored = b.overallmin_scored
     , a.feedback_avg_scored = b.overallavg_scored
     , a.feedback_st_dev = overallst_dev
     , a.feedback_variance = b.overallvarian
     , a.quescat_max_scored = b.cat_max_scored
     , a.quescat_min_scored = b.cat_min_scored
     , a.quescat_avg_scored = b.cat_avg_scored
     , a.quescat_st_dev = cat_st_dev
     , a.quescat_variance = b.cat_varian
     , a.ques_max_scored = b.max_scored
     , a.ques_min_scored = b.min_scored
     , a.ques_avg_scored = b.avg_scored
     , a.ques_st_dev = st_dev
     , a.ques_vaiance = b.varian  
 WHERE type_row = 'feedback';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: I have already used below index:
ALTER TABLE feedback_details_fact ADD KEY ix3(feedback_entity_type_id,feedback_id,quest_category_id,queid,faculty_id,subject_id);
ALTER TABLE feedback_details_fact ADD KEY ix2(feedback_entity_type_id,feedback_id,feedback_window_id,quest_category_id,queid,faculty_id,subject_id);

ALTER TABLE feedback_response_fact ADD KEY ix3(feedback_id,que_category,queid,tot_que_cat_score,tot_que_score);
ALTER TABLE feedback_response_fact ADD KEY ix4(feedback_id,feedback_window_id,que_category,queid,tot_que_cat_score,tot_que_score);

Comment: I'm not even going to try to read that

Comment: It's improbable that this query returns a valid result, because there are several non-aggregated columns missing from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Can't answer without knowing which table `tot_que_score` is in.

Comment: Ditto for `faculty_id`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I need to know some things not listed above - engine, primary key, datatypes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE `feedback_response_fact` (
  `entity_id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `org_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_fact_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_fact_dcnid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_dcnid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_detail_id` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_detail_dcnid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_window_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `uniquekey` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `uniquekeyStatus` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `responded` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_answers_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_answers_dcnid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `que_category` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `que_type_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `queid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ansoptionid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ansOptionScore` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerid` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerFirstName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerMiddleName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerLastName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerEmailID` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `respondent_student_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `respondent_student_Fact_entity_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `respondent_employee_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `respondent_employee_Fact_entity_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `anstext_Obj` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `anstext_Subj` text,
  `feedback_responded_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailsenddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedbackpercentagescore_for_respondent` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_score_For_respondent` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_is_active` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `answer_rowstate` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `answer_logged_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mart_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_que_cat_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_que_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_entity_mapping_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_user_id` (`userid`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_fact_id` (`feedback_fact_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_id` (`feedback_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_detail_id` (`feedback_detail_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_window_id` (`feedback_window_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_answers_id` (`feedback_answers_id`),
  KEY `idx_que_category` (`que_category`),
  KEY `idx_groupid` (`groupid`),
  KEY `idx_queid` (`queid`),
  KEY `idx_userid` (`userid`)

### ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=373426 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `feedback_details_fact` (
  `entity_id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feedback_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_dcnid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedbackname` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_from_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_to_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed_permanently` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_type_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedbackURL` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_window_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `windowname` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `windowstartdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `windowenddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `window_end_hr` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `window_end_min` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `window_start_hr` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `window_start_min` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_entity_mapping_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_entity_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_entity_type_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_type_name` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faculty_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `faculty_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_no` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_name` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_name` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_code` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_type_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_type_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_type_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_code` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_group_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_group_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resource_group_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slot_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timetable_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_feedback` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quest_category_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quest_group_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ques_type_Id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_type_name` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `queid` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_mandatory` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quesequence` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ansoption` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_sequence` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionScore` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ques_max_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_max_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fedback_max_group_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `fedback_max_category_score` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedback_is_active` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `feedback_rowstate` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latest_flag` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `active_flag` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowstate` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionmapping_active_flag` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionmapping_rowstate` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionmapping_last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionmapping_logged_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionmapping_logged_by` varchar(252) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitymapping_logged_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitymapping_logged_by` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitymapping_is_active` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitymapping_is_rowstate` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitymapping_last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionmapping_last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionmapping_logged_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionmapping_rowstate` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionmapping_is_active` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mart_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `anonymous` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `activity_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `faculty_for_slot_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_group_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_id` (`feedback_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_window_id` (`feedback_window_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_entity_mapping_id` (`feedback_entity_mapping_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_entity_id` (`feedback_entity_id`),
  KEY `idx_feedback_entity_type_id` (`feedback_entity_type_id`),
  KEY `idx_quest_category_id` (`quest_category_id`),
  KEY `idx_quest_group_id` (`quest_group_id`),
  KEY `idx_queid` (`queid`),
  KEY `idx_ansoption` (`ansoption`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=169407 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: These two tables are used to update table feedback_aggregated_fact

Comment: I just want to know is this way of updating table table is correct or not...as it is taking time